# Generate html dynamically and load after every page

Tags: python, flask

I'll try to describe my problem;

Calling `\user_favorite` and generating the html with dynamic data and extending it to `_base.html` where `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` is. A few lines below I got  `{% block recent_posts %}{% endblock %}` at the `_base.html`also, which `recent_posts.html` supposed to be added and this is going to be at the end of every page.

Sample:
`

```
# _base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>....</head>
<body>.....
# bunch of divs
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
#divs
{% block recent_posts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

`

But `recent_posts` page has to be generated dynamically also. How can I make a GET request to `\recent_posts` when I'm already rendering the results of `GET \user_favorite` so I can collect the data at the backend and render `recent_posts.html` which is going to extend `_base.html`

I don't think I can use `{%include 'recent_posts.html %}` because it takes what ever the created html was. I need to make a `GET` request to create the page.

It is confusing, I know. I think I'm trying to do something wrong. What is the best practice here?

Comment: I think I can render a mutual template with the data of both pages(`recent_posts` and `user_favorite`) and extend that to `_base.html`. Is this the best practice? What do you do when you need to render a dynamically generated html at the end of every(most) pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make multiple GET requests to resources,In your case:

```
GET \user_favorite
GET \recent_posts
```

I suggest using ajax.

In the header, make two GET request. After all the results are returned. Render the page afterwards.

A simple tutorial is at : [AJAX with jQuery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/)

Edit: You can make two templates, it is possible. It is just a design thing.

Comment: I've tried the `ajax` before and I've noticed that the `GET \recent_posts` is happening but I'm not seeing the html on the page.

Comment: Can you verify anything actually returns from the get request?

Comment: Yea, I can actually see the return `data` in the console

Comment: How about If i ajax request the URL at the head and prepare the html on the background and than `include` it here: `{% block recent_posts %}{% endblock %}`

I think that would work.